# Explanation about return object of class example

Tags: java, object, return, arguments, parameter-passing

I have this example ,and i need to know if the object class (ob2) in the second method came as argument from return object in the first method??

can anyone explain this example to me?

```
public class C {

  public B getObject(){

   B ob2 = new B ();

   return ob2; //return type
   }

   public void f3(A ob2){

   ob2.f1 (); //local variable or argument
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ob2 in method f3 comes from argument. For example:

```
C c = new C();
A ob2 = new A();
c.f3(ob2)
```

Comment: You mean ob2 not came from return ob2 (return object in the first method getObject,there is no any relation between them?

Comment: But i read this in someone research (one type of coupling between objects is return type,Through return types: Take an example of program that will explain the case of coupling through argument passing through return types.(He say that coupling through argument passing through return type

Comment: ,so what meaning of this (Take an example of program that will explain the case of coupling through argument passing through return types)why he say that through argument passing??

Comment: can you explain me ,the lines that i write previously in the previous comments?\

Answer (score 0):

```
public class C {

    public B getObject(){  
         B ob2 = new B ();
        return ob2; //return type 
    }

    public void f3(A ob2){
         ob2.f1 (); //local variable or argument 
   }                                                                                   
}
```

I think your question is bit confusing.
You had provided in the signature that the return type of the first function is of type ' B '.
But you are expecting the Argument of type A from type B
Here the signature of second function expects argument of type A not B

Comment: I know this and i know the ob2 is instance of class A,but i read this in someone research (one type of coupling between objects is return type,Through return types: Take an example of program that will explain the case of
coupling through argument passing through return types.  
class B extends A{ //inheritance
public void f2() {

System.out.print ("s2");
}}
public class C {
public B getObject(){
B ob2 = new B ();
return ob2; //return type}
public void f3(A ob2){
ob2.f1 (); //local variable or argument
}

Comment: class A {
public void f1() {
B ob2=new B ();
ob2.f2 ();
System.out.print ("s1");
}
}
class B extends A{ //inheritance
public void f2() {

System.out.print ("s2");
}}
public class C {
public B getObject(){
B ob2 = new B ();
return ob2; //return type
}
public void f3(A ob2){
ob2.f1 (); //local variable or argument
}